# Converting a letter to a digit for phone number in Python

Tags: python, phone-number

I'm trying to write a program that prompts the user to enter a phone number as a string. The input can contain letters, and the program translates a letter (whether uppercase or lowercase) to a digit and leaves all other characters intact. Here's what I have so far:

```
def getNumber(uppercaseLetter):
    if uppercaseLetter == 'A':
        number = 2
    elif uppercaseLetter == 'B':
        number = 2
    elif uppercaseLetter == 'C':
        number = 2
    elif uppercaseLetter == 'D':
        number = 3
    elif uppercaseLetter == 'E':
        number = 3
    elif uppercaseLetter == 'F':
        number = 3
    elif uppercaseLetter == 'G':
        number = 4
    elif uppercaseLetter == 'H':
        number = 4
    elif uppercaseLetter == 'I':
        number = 4
    elif uppercaseLetter == 'J':
        number = 5
    elif uppercaseLetter == 'K':
        number = 5
    elif uppercaseLetter == 'L':
        number = 5
    elif uppercaseLetter == 'M':
        number = 6
    elif uppercaseLetter == 'N':
        number = 6
    elif uppercaseLetter == 'O':
        number = 6
    elif uppercaseLetter == 'P':
        number = 7
    elif uppercaseLetter == 'Q':
        number = 7
    elif uppercaseLetter == 'R':
        number = 7
    elif uppercaseLetter == 'S':
        number = 7
    elif uppercaseLetter == 'T':
        number = 8
    elif uppercaseLetter == 'U':
        number = 8
    elif uppercaseLetter == 'V':
        number = 8
    elif uppercaseLetter == 'W':
        number = 9
    elif uppercaseLetter == 'X':
        number = 9
    elif uppercaseLetter == 'Y':
        number = 9
    elif uppercaseLetter == 'Z':
        number = 9
    return number

def translateNumber():
    phoneNumber = str(input("Enter a string: "))
    for char in phoneNumber:
        if char in    ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']:
        getNumber(char)
        return char
        else:
            return char
        print(phoneNumber)
```

For some reason I can't get it to work, and I'm unsure what the issue is. Can someone please help me with the solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not explaining your code (already done by Chrisitan). Here is just a way:

```
>>> char_numbers = [('abc',2), ('def',3), ('ghi',4), ('jkl',5), ('mno',6), ('pqrs',7), ('tuv',8), ('wxyz',9)]
>>> char_num_map = {c:v for k,v in char_numbers for c in k}
>>> phone = "JUST 1 NUMBER"
>>> result = "".join(str(char_num_map.get(v,v)) for v in phone.lower())
>>> result
'5878 1 686237'
```

Comment: The issue is that if I'm trying to type in a number, say: 1-800-Flowers, but I want it to return 1-800-3569377. How do I do this?

Comment: It is already doing that. Just populate the `phone` variable with "1-800-Flowers"...

Comment: Thank you! My mistake on that one. I really appreciate the help

Answer (score 3):

Your function `getNumber()` returns a number, but you are not storing it. To store it, assign the result to a variable, and then return it:

```
def translateNumber():
    phoneNumber = str(input("Enter a string: "))
    for char in phoneNumber:
        if char in    ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']:
            result = getNumber(char)
            return result
        else:
            return char
```

Comment: This solution actually answers the question "why doesn't my function work".  The other solutions are other ways to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getNumber(uppercaseLetter):  
#Create a function to return phone number
    ascii = ord(uppercaseLetter) # get ascii using ord() method
    # returns all the possible digits
    if ascii < 83:
        Number = (ascii - 65)//3+2
    elif ascii == 83:
        Number = 7
    elif ascii >83 and ascii < 97:
        Number = 8
    #If the input char is a digit, returns the digit
    elif isdigit(uppercaseLetter) == True:
        Number = uppercaseLetter
    else: 
        Number = 9
    Number = str(Number)
    return Number 

def main():     # Define the main function
    output = "" # Setting the output as a blank string
    str = input('Enter a string: \n') # Get input from user
    lst = [x for x in str] # convert all char in str to a list
    for x in str:
        # If the char x is alphabet make it to the uppercase
        if isdigit(x) == False and isalnum(x) == True:
           uppercaseLetter = x.upper()
           result = getNumber(uppercaseLetter)
           output = output + result
           if isalnum(x) == False: # If the char x is a digit
               output = output + x
        else:
            output = output + x
    print(output)        
main() # Excute the main function
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Thanks this answer got me going. I wanted to print number for alphabet entered by user. But the condition in code "elif ascii >83 and ascii < 97:" returns 8 for even alphabets - w,x,y,z whereas it should return 9 for those. Please check and correct.